# List physical disks in c on FreeBSD system call

Tags: c, freebsd

Could you point me in right direction? Now I am looking system call `g_io_getattr`.. 
I do not want to call subprocess.
The return would be e.g. 'da0', 'da1' or 'ada0'...

Comment: I want regular user can get this info. Like `geom disk list`

Comment: Relevant project: https://bitbucket.org/arrowd/bsdisks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely  going to want to be working with FreeBSD's [libgeom](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libgeom&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) - specifically geom_gettree().  [The source to freebsd's partedit](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/usr.sbin/bsdinstall/partedit/partedit.c) -  shows it being used and the resulting structure being iterated through in the read_geom_mesh and related functions in order to get a list of the disks.  What appears to be the [source of the geom program](http://web.mit.edu/ebj/Desktop/ebj/MacData/afs/sipb/project/freebsd/head/sbin/geom/core/geom.c) also demonstrates some usage of the geom_gettree function and iterating through its returned structure.